# Why does "from file import class work", and not "import file"?

Tags: python, class, import

I made a class in a single file and it looks like below:

```
class Robot():

    def __init__(self, name, desc, color, owner):
    # initializes our robot

        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.color = color
        self.owner = owner

    def drive_forward(self):
    #simulates driving forward
    print(self.name.title() + " is driving" + " forward " + str(self.duration)+ " milliseconds")

    def drive_backwards(self):
    print(self.name.title() + " is driving" + " backwards " + str(self.duration) + " milliseconds")

    def turn_left(self):
    print(self.name.title() + " is turning " + " left " + str(self.duration) + " milliseconds")

    def turn_right(self):
    print(self.name.title() + " is turning " + " right " + str(self.duration)  + " milliseconds")
```

and I was trying to import this file to another file, so I can 
instantiate it and see how OOP works like.

And the other file that I was trying to import the class and instantiate looks like below:

```
from robot_sample_class  import Robot

my_robot = Robot("Nomad", "Autonomous rover", "Black", "JAY")

print("My robot is a " + my_robot.desc + " called " + my_robot.name)

my_robot.drive_forward()
my_robot.drive_backwards()
my_robot.turn_left()
my_robot.turn_right()
```

This code works well on the Python Shell; however, if I just write

import "robot_sample_class" alone rather than "from robot_sample_class  import Robot"

It doesn't work and it spits out an error message such as:

my_robot = Robot("Nomad", "Autonomous rover", "Black", "JAY")
NameError: name 'Robot' is not defined

Why is this the case? I thought importing the entire file will allow me to
access everything in that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import robot_sample_class
```

means you need to write:

```
robot_sample_class.Robot(...)
```

If you want to import everything into the global namespace, use:

```
from robot_sample_class import *
```

Although this is not recommended for code that is meant to last.